# Use of object_name in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formbuilder

```
Rails 3.2
```

Inside a form, for instance:

```
<%= form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

If I use:

```
f.object
```

Then I would be referring to: @ticket

What would: f.object_name be?

Comment: Its the key used in the params - like for example `:user`. Its derived from calling [`param_key`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-c-param_key) on the model.

Comment: @max not sure I understand. The Ticket model is: class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: If you look at the resulting params hash from submitting the form you can see that the inputs are nested under a key - which is the same as `f.object_name`.